# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page - this error pops up in the guest page whenever i create account or login

Tags: magento2

I am working on a windows 10, using Xampp v3.2.2 
my *Magento version is 2.3.0*,
php v7.2.9
so whenever i try to create an account or try to add products to my cart i get this message - **Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page**

Answer (score 0):

do you have any caching setup?  3rd party cache modules, not the built in magento ones? 
also, can you try it on an incognito window of your browser.  i've seen sessions get messed up.

Comment: I tried the incognito window, clearing cache of the browser and also in my root directory var/cache folder. but i have the same error message 'Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page'.

Comment: can you inspect the page which has the add to cart button and search for "form_key"  it should look like this: <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="xW7Oc9aG8vtGVGfI"> with a different value.  there should be one for each add to cart button and they should all be the same.  if you are on a list view, search the source for the value.  you should have at least as many as there are products on the page.  on mine i have 11 with 10 products and 1 login modal.

Comment: if you don't have a value or the values on them do not match, then that will help us solve your issue.